# Confusion with temperature and pressure relationship

Tags: pressure, temperature, density

Let's say we have 1 m³ of a heat transfer fluid ( eg, novec 1230 ) in a container matching the fluid volume so now if we heat the fluid to let's say 300°c

Will the fluid attain equilibrium at a critical point? (As the pressure raises the boiling point will also rise and keeping the volume unchanged)
What would the critical point be at that temperature?
Is there a mathematical way of finding the critical point for any fluid?( Or is it just experimentally found )
What would the pressure be inside the container be when the fluid is at 300°c?

Answer (score 0):

The increase in pressure $P$ per unit increase in temperature $T$ of any system at constant volume $V$ can be expressed as $$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V.$$

For a gas at temperature $T$, we have $PV=znRT$, where $z$ is the [compressibility factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility_factor) and $R$ is the [gas constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant), so

$$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V=\frac{nR}{V}\left[z+T\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial T}\right)_V\right],$$

which is just $\frac{nR}{V}=\frac{P}{T}$ for the ideal gas ($z=1$).

For condensed matter, the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) gives

$$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V=-\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right)_T=\alpha K,$$

where $\alpha$ is the constant-pressure thermal expansion coefficient and $K$ is the isothermal bulk modulus. From the material properties of the substance of interest, one can integrate this relationship so obtain the temperature-dependent pressure at constant volume, and one can compare these state variables to those at the critical point.

As an example, consider water:
[image]

(Note that "0.00611 MPa" should read "0.000611 MPa"—the authors missed a zero.)

[image]

Starting at the triple point at 0.01°C, 0.000611 MPa, we see that with increasing heating at constant volume (a specific volume of 0.001 m³/kg), the path moves through the liquid-water region (straight upward in the V–T plot). It's indicated that the critical temperature of 373.9°C is then exceeded at a pressure exceeding 22.064 MPa.

Regardless of your substance, equilibrium will be attained when the temperature matches that of the surrounding environment. However, there are no fast rules on whether this temperature will be subcritical or supercritical, or what equilibrium phase will be found.